# How to compare two sheets and delete/add any column with a distinct value in row 1? Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to compare two sheets (based on header values in row 1) and delete any column with a unique value (without a match). For example, Assuming Sheet1, Row 1 data and Sheet 2, Row 1 are uniform, if a user adds/deletes a column within any sheet, I want to always match the number of columns in both sheets with their values

Screenshots of sheets headings.

IF both sheets looks like this
[image]

And a user adds a new Column N
[image]

Or delete column N

[image]

How can I ensure that both sheet matches by deleting the odd/distinct column in Sheet 1?

I have tried modifying this code below but I can't just get the unique one out. This code only look for headers with a defined value.

```
function deleteAloneColumns(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumnPos = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headers = sheet.getRange( 1 ,1, 1, lastColumnPos ).getValues()[0];
  for( var i = lastColumnPos ; i < 1; i--){
    if( headers[i] === "alone" ) sheet.deleteColumn(i);
  }
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( 'Job done!' );
}
```

Any help to compare and delete the column with the unique value will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Smith O! Could you please clarify what does "unique" value mean in the context of your script? Do you want header cell value to be configurable or to only delete cols  in sheet 2 whose header value is different from sheet 1?

Comment: I meant distinct value, without any match. For example, Assuming Sheet1, Row 1 data and Sheet 2, Row 1 are uniform, if a user adds/deletes a column within any sheet, I want to always match the number of columns in both sheets with their values

Comment: Please share images of your sheets

Comment: Added screenshots as requested

Comment: ok, the first part sounds easy enough - for each cell value in `getValues()[0]` in target sheet (assuming you are only interested in header row) if validation sheet `getValues()[0]` does not contain (with `indexOf===-1`, for example) the value => delete column. What bugs me is the second part - you need to do the reverse, and delete a column in validation sheet with header not found in the target sheet?

Comment: What I wanted is to always reconcile the target sheet with the validation sheet. So I dont really need to change anything in the validation sheet. Just want to ensure that the target sheet always matches the validation sheet based on column headings

Comment: Sure, just what is the preferred way if a user *deletes* a column - is it restored from validation sheet (the other one) or is a column in validation sheet deleted to match the edit?

Comment: Validation sheet is copied from a different spreadsheet, so it's possible that it has more columns. In that case, I'll just simply want to update (insert new columns) the target sheet. In the same way, if validation sheet doesn't have as much columns, target sheet columns should match it.

Comment: Thanks, now sounds much clearer - apart from the suggestion to look for unmatch with `indexOf` or comparing vals one by one in a loop, we will take a look and either me or someone else will post a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Balancing sheets based on header row values mismatch.

**Solution**

If I understood you correctly, you have a source sheet against which validation is run and two primary use cases: user adds a new column named differently than any other column (if you want to check that the column strictly matches the one in sheet1, it is easy to modify) in source sheet or deletes one that should be there.

```
const balanceSheets = (sourceShName = 'Sheet1',targetShName = 'Sheet2') => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const s1 = ss.getSheetByName(sourceShName);
  const s2 = ss.getSheetByName(targetShName);

  const s2lcol = s2.getLastColumn();

  //keep all vals from source to reduce I/O
  const s1DataVals = s1.getDataRange().getValues();

  const s2Vals = s2.getRange(1, 1, 1, s2lcol).getValues();

  const h1Vals = s1DataVals[0];
  const h2Vals = s2Vals[0];

  //assume s1 is source (validation) sheet
  //assume s2 is target sheet that a user can edit

  //case 1: target has value not present in source -> delete column in target
  let colIdx = 0;
  h2Vals.forEach(value => {
    const isOK = h1Vals.some(val => val===value);

    isOK ? colIdx++ : s2.deleteColumn(colIdx+1);
  });

  //case 2: target does not have values present in source -> append column from source
  h1Vals.forEach((value,index) => {
    const isOK = h2Vals.some(val => val===value);
    !isOK && s2.insertColumnAfter(index);

    const valuesToInsert = s1DataVals.map(row => [row[index]]);

    const numRowsToInsert = valuesToInsert.length;

    s2.getRange(1,index+1, numRowsToInsert,1).setValues(valuesToInsert);
  });

};
```

**Showcase**

Here is a small demo of how it works as a macros:

[image: Balancer demo]

**Notes**

1. Solving your problem with two `forEach` is suboptimal, but I kept number of I/O low (it can be lowered further by, for example, moving `deleteColum` out of the loop while only keeping track of column indices).
2. The script uses ES6 capabilities provided by V8, so please, be careful (although I would recommend migrating as soon as possible - even if you encounter bugs / inconsistencies , it is worth more than it costs.
3. **UPD** made script more flexible by moving sheet names to parameter list.
4. **UPD2** after discussing the issue with `deleteColumn()` behaviour, the answer is updated to keep column pointer in bounds (for those curious about it - `forEach` kept incrementing the `index`, while `deleteColumn` reduced bounds for any given index).

**Reference**

1. `insertColumnAfter()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertcolumnafterafterposition)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but this looks awesome already. Many thanks, Oleg

Comment: Hope that's what you are looking for - tested on a sample spreadsheet, maybe you would need to tweak it for your needs, but it should be easily configurable - please, let me know if you encounter any issues

Comment: I assume it worked well on your dataset then? Glad to hear if so - you are welcome, we are always here to help)

Comment: I'm still yet to test but I'll tweak or contact you when required. I'm very happy with this

Comment: Can you help pls? I keep getting the "Invalid property Id" error from this line "const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();"

Comment: hm, are you on V8? Your manifest should have a `"runtimeVersion": "V8"` if so

Comment: Yes. I was able to bypass those errors, but isn't making the changes yet. Still investigating...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207953/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-smith-o).